# How often can a U.S. passport holder exit/enter Morocco?

Tags: usa, morocco

Does anyone how many times a year one can enter and exit and RE-ENTER Morocco as a United States passport holder? For instance, Schengen countries have the 90/180 rule. I've looked everywhere for the information and there is nothing out there, making me think it's a non-issue, but I'd like to make sure!

Comment: Check out http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/morocco.html ....I didn't see anything about a limited number of entries per year, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Three is no "in the U.S. one can leave and re-enter 3 times in a row" rule.  This is, at best, a dangerous myth.